How do I allow a background image for my galleries to scale as the gallery css does?
I have added a several lightbox galleries to my site with the following CSS code as a background to all. I am wondering how to scale this background image so that it scales with the images and when the website is eventually published will look as good on mobile as it does on web currently.
.slide-show_containers {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2000;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(img/background/Frame.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


object-fit: cover
Read more about object-fit
